# Yii2 framework tables join

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have the following relations defined in the model

```
public function getApplication()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Applications::className(), ['application_id' => 'application_id']);
}

public function getAccount()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Accounts::className(), ['account_id' => 'account_id']);
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Users::className(), ['user_id' => 'oncall_id']);
}
```

And in the view:

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table  table-bordered table-hover table-striped'],
'columns' => [
    ['attribute' => 'oncalls.start_date', 'value' => 'start_date', 'headerOptions' => ['width' => '10%']],
    ['label' => 'Shift', 'value' => function($data) {
            if ($data->shift_start && $data->shift_end)
                return $data->shift_start . " -> " . $data->shift_end;
        }],
    'account.account_name',
    'application.application_name',
    'user.real_name',
    ['label' => 'Priority', 'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
            if ($dataProvider->priority == 1)
                return "Primary";
            else
                return "Secondary";
        }],
    'user.phone_1',
    'user.phone_2',
],
```

]);

However, in the debugger, it seems that there are excessive queries being made.
For every assignment record, there's a select query for the appropriate table (users,applications,account)

How can I avoid having those queries and simply have a join statement with all those values?

Comment: u can edit dataProvider that pass to gridview in that searchmodel

Comment: @mohsen, what do you mean edit the dataProvider, the relations are set in the model, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "with" or "joinWith" on your query.

```
$dataProvider->query->with('account', 'application', 'user');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail